# AFX_WM_DRAW2D messages when screen is asleep

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a problem with a progress bar that is implemented through adding a D2D object in MFC library. 
I set up a message map to my function that keeps redrawing the progress bar based on some calculations:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProgressControl, CStatic)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_DRAW2D, &CProgressControl::OnDraw2D)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

My problem is that when the user locks out of the computer and the screen is asleep my drawing function does not seem to be called. It seems that the D2D notification message `AFX_WM_DRAW2D` is never sent to redraw when the screen is asleep.

I have tried to search for information on this online but did not find anything good about what might happen differently when the screen is asleep. I would appreciate any insight anyone might have on this.

Comment: I know that when a screen saver is displayed, Windows switches to an entirely different desktop with nothing but the screen saver displayed on it. Probably the same thing happens when there's no screen saver. Since the regular user desktop isn't being displayed, Windows won't try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like this could be a normal behavior. Do you get any messages when your app is minimized or the computer is locked? I suspect that not.

Anyways, why should this bother you? Obviously your progress bar is invisible at the time, so why bother with the panting? You should be happy - Windows has an optimization for your program.

However if you do anything else besides painting in the painting messages, then I'd advise moving it elsewhere, as it is not that right place for it anyway. Paint message handlers should ONLY contain paint logic, and be prepared to be called at any time (or not at all).

Comment: Its ok that it does not draw when asleep but my problem is that when the program is done running the progress bar gets stuck where it was when thw screen went asleep. I am missing the last call to redraw basically and I am trying to workaround that somehow. If  I can force it to redraw when the screen is asleep it would be one way to do that

Comment: @virtore - Have you tried calling [`InvalidateRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002\(v=vs.85\).aspx) or it's MFC moral equivalent? That should set the window in "needs redraw" state until it actually gets a redraw. Also, this is the preferred way of "redrawing" your window on demand.

Comment: I tried some forms of Invalidate() function but it does not seem to work form where I was trying to call it so far. I can keep trying though. My problem is that I am just trying to fix this little bug without an extensive rewrite of to much code. So I figured the easy hack would be somehow to override the lack of updates when the screen is sleeping

Comment: @virtore - Try putting a call to `Invalidate()` at the end of your process, after which the progress bar isn't expected to change anymore.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I am in a bit of a bind because the way this code is currently written my OnDraw2D function is called from the mfc100.dll which is exactly the call seems to be going to sleep on me. So Invalidate() also never gets called in any reasonable location I can place it. I realize this getting a bit vague now and I appreciate your answers but short of a more extensive rewrite my only option does only appear to be somehow forcing mfc to keep redrawing when the screen is asleep. I am wondering if that is possible at all

Comment: Actually done some more debugging and it seems that the drawing function does get called when the screen is off except windows decides not to draw anything. So when I insert an Invalidate() call when the bar value is 100% the effect is that the bar gets erased but is never redrawn, so now instead of an incomplete progress bar I have an empty one when the run is finished. I still think I need some kind of redraw override setting to make this work easily

Comment: @virtore - Once more, your program should be like this: There should be some variable where the progress is stored. The paint procedure looks at this variable and draws the right progress bar. It does this whenever asked, which might be a lot of times or just once. The worker process periodically updates the variable and calls `Invalidate()`. This may or may not actually redraw the progress bar, but the worker shouldn't care. Last but not least, Windows itself will also sometimes call `Invalidate()` when the window needs redrawing (like after sleep).

Comment: @virtore - The actual drawing will take place in the WM_PAINT message, which is a special kind of message. Calling `Invalidate()` doesn't send the message, it sets a special flag which says "Please redraw at your earliest convenience". Your main message loop will then look at this flag and generate the WM_PAINT message when there are no more other messages in the queue. The only thing I'm not sure about is how D2D interferes with this.

Comment: I appreciate your answers. I call Invalidate() when my progress bar value is 100% but this does not seem to work when the screen is asleep. After sleep Invalidate() gets auto called only if the execution is still in progress in which case the progress bar jumps to the current value but if the program terminated already the last redraw message gets lost. I will try doing a manual call to WM_PAINT somehow when the bar value is 100% to force it to redraw

Answer (score 0):

Search the MFC sources for AFX_WM_DRAW2D and you'll see in wincore.cpp that the message is sent from a method called CWnd::DoD2DPaint() inbetween the render target's BeginDraw and EndDraw calls.

Therefore call DoD2DPaint to force a repaint. I did this on the sample CMFCD2DWalkthroughView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg482848.aspx) in the OnSize method to ensure that the gradient is updated and painted when the window is resized instead of the size/paint being out of sync.